# \@currname not working in MikTeX

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

A few weeks ago (like maybe 5?) `\@currname` worked fine.  Then I guess I updated MikTeX, which I do pretty often, and now it doesn't.  MWE:

```
% scrap.sty
\title{1\@currname2}

% scrap.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrap}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The title ends up as 12.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What did `\@currname` output previously? Perhaps you're looking for `\jobname`?

Comment: The name of the style file.

Comment: According to source2e, it is set by \@onefilewithoptions.  Presumably it is called by \usepackage.

Comment: I had to update MikTeX two times in a row to make it work properly. Maybe this works.

Comment: I am feeling silly.  Werner was right.  Everything is working after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default consequence of writing `\title{<stuff>}` results in `<stuff>` being stored inside `\@title`, which is eventually used by `\maketitle`. Moreover, `<stuff>` is not expanded at all, so using a macro that changes based on context may result in an unwanted outcome.

Ways around this could be to explicitly expand `\@currname` as part of the title. Two ways are:

```
\xdef\@title{1\@currname2}
```

or

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\title{1\@currname2}}\x
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{scrap.sty}
%\xdef\@title{1\@currname2}% Option 1
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\title{1\@currname2}}\x% Option 2
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{scrap}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```